# Flutter: Using SliverChildBuilderDelegate in a GridView.custom, Get Widget Constraints for Draggable

Tags: flutter, gridview, drag-and-drop

I am attempting to create a custom grid view, and i need to put constraints on the Draggable feedback or it expands to cover the entire screen.  Normally in builders, there is a constraints variable passed, but there is not one in the SliverChildBuilderDelegate.  What would be the best way to limit the size of the feedback of the draggable to the current size of the widget?  The ?'s in feedback is where the variable should go.

```
return GridView.custom(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      primary: false,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      controller: _scrollController,
      physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
      gridDelegate: SliverQuiltedGridDelegate(
        crossAxisCount: 4,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        repeatPattern: QuiltedGridRepeatPattern.inverted,
        pattern: widget.pattern,
      ),
      childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        childCount: widget.children.length,
        (context, index) {
          var selectedWidget = widget.children[index];
          return LongPressDraggable<GlobalKey>(
                  data: selectedWidget.key,
                  onDragStarted: _onDragStarted,
                  onDragEnd: _onDragEnd,
                  feedback:
                      SizedBox(width: ?, height:?, child: selectedWidget),
                  childWhenDragging: Container(),
                  child: selectedWidget,
                   
                )}))
```